# Scale NSView centered

Tags: macos, scale, nsview

I need to scale an NSView around it's center. 
I tried using CATransform3DMakeScale and it worked to scale the view towards it's corner but I couldn't achieve to center it. I tried to set the layers anchor point to .5, .5 but that didn't work.
I tried using scaleUnitSquareToSize but I ran into the problem that this seems unresetable without a lot of work.

In the end I need to be able to set the scale of an NSView to something like 0.8 and have it zoom out around it's center and be able to set the scale to 1 again to reset it.

Answer (score 4):

Added a frame fix for @fyasar's answer, works for me on MacOS:

```
CGRect frame = layer.frame;
layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);
layer.frame = frame; // Fix the location shift caused from anchor change
```

Comment: Note that if the layer's transform is not identity, resetting the frame may make change the layer's bounds.size. A better approach is to move the position back.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced with smilar problem. 
Please be sure exeute that line before construct `CABasicAnimation`.

```
layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);
```

So, that worked for me.

Good luck

Comment: Added another answer with a frame fix + 1

Answer (score 1):

If you can require 10.8, then you could call `NSScrollView`'s function:

```
- (void)setMagnification:(CGFloat)magnification centeredAtPoint:(NSPoint)point
```