# NSView not scaling all content

Tags: objective-c, macos, scale, nsview

I'm trying to scale an NSView for a larger display when I'm testing on my Mac screen, so I can see everything in proportion.

```
NSRect wFrame = self.window.frame;
wFrame.origin.x = 200;
wFrame.origin.y = 100; // from bottom of my screen
wFrame.size.width = 1080 * 0.5; // so it will fit on my screen
wFrame.size.height = 1920 * 0.5;
[self.window setFrame:wFrame display:YES]; // the window is smaller, but not everything is scaled (e.g., font sizes)
```

That creates the correct size window, and most of the contents are drawn at half size. But, some things are not scaled.

1. An NSButton's title text is still the original, large size.  If the button contains an image, the image is scaled properly.
2. The content of a WebView are not rendered at the small size.

How can I scale all of the content, including button titles and Webview content?

Comment: Can you show the code where you draw the views you want to scale?

Comment: I don't think the fonts are scaled with the view. You may have to calculate the required font size and change it accordingly. That could also be the reason why the button is not scaling. It's probably keeping the size it needs to accommodate the font.

Comment: @rocky: The window has one NSView (in and XIB), and that view has a bunch of subviews -- a dozen buttons and a WebView.  Nothing fancy.  I don't do any of my own drawing.  The sizes of all those controls scale properly.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/33293423/236415](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33293423/236415http://)

I wrapped my full sized NSView (and its subviews) in an NSScrollView (sized for my screen) and then set the magnification to 0.5.